# Parsing a text file in Java to obtain a HashMap of fields

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse multiple files and split them up into a set of fields in a HashMap. This is a specimen file.

```
COCONUT OIL CONTRACT TO CHANGE - DUTCH TRADERS

    ROTTERDAM, March 18 - Contract terms for trade in coconut
oil are to be changed from long tons to tonnes with effect from
the Aug/Sep contract onwards, Dutch vegetable oil traders said.
    Operators have already started to take account of the
expected change and reported at least one trade in tonnes for
Aug/Sept shipment yesterday.
```

I need the program to parse this document into fields in a custom Document Class which has keys, FileName, File Title, place, Date, Author, contents, category.

This is what I've tried doing about it.

```
public static Document parse(String filename) {

        File f = new File(filename);

        if (f.isFile()){



            String fileId;
            if (filename.indexOf(".") > 0) {
                fileId = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("."));
            }
            String category = f.getParent();

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);

            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            int len = in.read(buf);
            while(len > 0){
               ..........
            }
            in.close();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry what you try to accomplish here? :O

Comment: Well, that's a start but it'll be hard to continue in the same manner. If I were you, I'd stop writing code now and first of all figure out what high level steps needed to be taken. Write the steps down on a piece of paper. `1. Read the file fully into a string. 2. Extract file title ...` and so on. Then you can start coding it step by step, testing the results after each step.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help you:

```
try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("myFile.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuffer contentBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        boolean foundTitle = false;
        boolean foundPlaceAndDate = false;
        String date = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.matches("^[a-z-A-Z0-9].*") && !foundTitle) {
                // If line starts with a letter or number and has no title yet, that's the title
                System.out.println("Title: " + line);
                foundTitle = true;
            } else if (line.matches("^[\\ \t].*") && !foundPlaceAndDate) {
                // If line starts with a space or tab and it's out first paragraph, then this paragraph has place and date
                System.out.println("Place: " + line.trim().substring(0, line.trim().indexOf(",")));
                date = line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(",") + 1, line.trim().indexOf("-")).trim();
                System.out.println("Date: " + date);
                foundPlaceAndDate = true;
            }
            contentBuffer.append(line);
        }

        String content = contentBuffer.toString().substring(contentBuffer.toString().indexOf(date) + date.length() + 2).trim();
        System.out.println("Content: " + content);

        br.close();
        fstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Oh no! I got the following error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

The output will be:

**Title**: COCONUT OIL CONTRACT TO CHANGE - DUTCH TRADERS

**Place**: ROTTERDAM

**Date**: March 18

**Content**: Contract terms for trade in coconutoil are to be changed from long tons to tonnes with effect fromthe Aug/Sep contract onwards, Dutch vegetable oil traders said.    Operators have already started to take account of theexpected change and reported at least one trade in tonnes forAug/Sept shipment yesterday.

Comment: this does get me started but I need to parse the file into a document class which looks like this.public class    Document {
 
 private HashMap<FieldNames, String[]> map;
 
 
 public Document() {
  map = new HashMap<FieldNames, String[]>();
 }
 
 
  
 public void setField(FieldNames fn, String... o) {
  map.put(fn, o);
 }
 
 
 
 
 public String[] getField(FieldNames fn) {
  return map.get(fn);
 }
}

Comment: All you need to do now is to fill the fields of your Document class. For example: `Document document = new Document(); document.setField("title", title);`